# Is it detrimental for an Oracle11g database to be shutdown every day. Databases housed on a AWS EC2 instances

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g

Managing an Oracle database 11g/Windows OS on a AWS EC2 instance. We shutdown the server at 1800 and start it up at 0600. I am trying to find out what are the effects on the database by starting it and stopping it everyday, if any? The database is set to shutdown immediate when server is shut down. I researched that as long as you shut the database down gracefully there shouldn't be any issues, but I also came across some information saying it could be detrimental to the database. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What information did you find, and did that offer any reason it could be detrimental? The only practical things I can think of off-hand are (a) that caches will be cleared on restart so you could see performance impacts, and (b) scheduled jobs won't run or will be interrupted; which could include stats gathering, backups and other housekeeping tasks. *Why* are you shutting it down every night?

Comment: It just stated that it could be detrimental with out much of a explanation, which lead me to asked this question. The customer is taking advantage of the feature in AWS of having the ability to turn the server on and off, to save money.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cost/benefit decision.  Shutting down the database will incur a performance penalty for your applications after restart.  I did a video with some simple demos of that here

https://youtu.be/C7iugiVM6Cg

But if you are not a high volume, high transaction user, and there are significant monetary savings for you in turning off the database, then go ahead. As others have said, there are a number of activities that typically occur overnight in an Oracle database that you might want to shift to another timeslot when your database is actually open.  Check out Oracle maintenance windows in the docs

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tasks.htm

to ensure that key activities (such as optimizer statistics) are not being sacrificed which would create problems down the track.

It would also be worth checking out just *how* much money you are saving, because if the database is not being aggressively used each night, then the financial cost might be a pittance anyway